# How can I get more leeks in Stardew Valley?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'd like to grow some spring forageables, but I'm lacking leeks to craft a 10-pack of seeds. Everything else I've got lots. I've been looking for 11 in-game days and I can't find any. Is there some way to obtain more leeks other than random chance of them appearing on the road?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Horseradish, when put in the Seedmaker, will produce Spring-seeds.

See:
http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Wild_Horseradish .

Answer (score -1):

Besides foraging and the spring seed group, you can also acquire and plant [mixed seeds](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Crops#Mixed_Seeds), which mature into a random seasonally-appropriate plant.

Comment: Not true, mixed seeds will grow specifically into crops, not forage.